# Error while generating thumbnail of video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Here is my code for generating thumbnail of video:

```
           NSString *getUrl = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"newpath"];
NSLog(@"getURL=%@",getUrl);
NSLog(@"newpath for url=%@",newPath);
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getUrl];
AVURLAsset *asset=[[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform=TRUE;
[asset release];
CMTime thumbTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,30);

AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef im, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error){
    if (result != AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {
        NSLog(@"couldn't generate thumbnail, error:%@", error);
    }
    [btnVideo setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:im] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   // thumbImg=[[UIImage imageWithCGImage:im] retain];
    [generator release];
};

CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(320, 180);
generator.maximumSize = maxSize;
[generator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:thumbTime]] completionHandler:handler];
```

when i use this code it gives the following error:

```
   couldn't generate thumbnail, error:Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo=0x5bbbb0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12935), NSUnderlyingError=0x59ae40 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12935.)", NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}
```

Can anyone suggest me what kind of error is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using video file from bundled then please follow the previous post : [AVURLAsset refuses to load video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101380/avurlasset-refuses-to-load-video)

This is really significant case.