# AVURLAsset - loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:requestedKeys

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, avurlasset

I'm using this code to load the values of key and play movie url.

```
[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:requestedKeys completionHandler:
     ^{                  
         dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), 
                        ^{                                                          
                            [self prepareToPlayAsset:asset withKeys:requestedKeys];
                        });
     }];
```

But sometimes the method prepareToPlayAsset cannot be run and i don't know why. Someone know the reason?

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101380/avurlasset-refuses-to-load-video) link

Comment: Not works. Because the url is likes this : http://localhost:12345/folderName/fileName.mp4