# Issue on capture screenshot of video

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

i want to take a screenshot of a video on my ipad app.

I searched on SO, and i found a lot of sample code. I tried everything but nothing seem to work.

I tried all of this methods:

---

#### 1) Try with : MPMoviePlayerController

```
- (void) previewWithPlayer:(NSString*)path image:(UIImageView*)imView
{
  MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
  UIImage *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
  [player stop];
  [player release];
  
  imView.image = thumbnail;
}
```

#### 2) Try with : AVAssetImageGenerator - v1

```
- (void) generateImage:(NSString*)path image:(UIImageView*)imView
{
  AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
  AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
  CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 1);
  UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:NULL]];
  imView.image = thumbnail;
}
```

#### 13) Try with : AVAssetImageGenerator - v2

```
- (void) generateImage:(NSString*)path image:(UIImageView*)imView
{
  AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path] options:nil];
  AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
  generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform=TRUE;
  [asset release];
  CMTime thumbTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(2,30);
  
  AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef im, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error){
    if (result != AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {
      NSLog(@"couldn't generate thumbnail, error:%@", error);
    }

    UIImage *thumbImg = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:im] retain];
    imView.image = thumbImg;
    [generator release];
  };
  
  CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(320, 180);
  generator.maximumSize = maxSize;
  [generator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:thumbTime]] completionHandler:handler];
}
```

But **nothig** works.
I tried with MOV, MP4, nothing.

Path is correct, video is working.

```
NSString *fPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"VideoA" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSLog(@"%@", fPath);
[self generateImage:fPath image:_ImgA];
```

What's could be the problem? My image view show nothing and no error are returned.
iOS is 6.0/5.1, on iPad simulator/device.

Video is 854×480 pixels, H.264, AAC. About 30Mb of size.

please help me because i'm going crazy with this issue.

thanks.

---

### edit

on device return this error:

> couldn't generate thumbnail, error:Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain
> Code=-1 "unknown error" UserInfo=0x1e0a2f30
> {NSUnderlyingError=0x1e0a3900 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
> (OSStatus error -12935.)", NSLocalizedDescription=unknown error}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved.
The trick: use `fileURLWithPath:`, not `URLWithString:`. Apparently the difference is really, really significant.

thanks to Noah. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4201419/88461

Comment: I had the same issue trying to playback a video that I had recorded using AVCaptureMovieFileOutput.  Using fileURLWithPath instead of URLWithString when loading the video fixed it for me as well