# iOS Swift : Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12792?

Tags: ios, error-handling, avfoundation, nserror, video-thumbnails

I'm trying to get video thumbnails with the following code:

```
let asset = AVAsset(URL: url)
    let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true

    do {
        let cgImage = try imgGenerator.copyCGImageAtTime(CMTimeMake(1, 30), actualTime: nil)
        let uiImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
        imageview.image = uiImage
    }
    catch let error as NSError
    {
        print("Image generation failed with error \(error)")
    }
```

Sometimes it works and sometime it doesn't showing the following error:

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could
>   not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could
>   not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x14eab520 {Error
>   Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12792 "(null)"},
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12792)}

I have tried to figure out what is `Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12792` but I don't understand how I can get more details about this error code. How can I convert this error code into a string to get relevant information about what this error means?

Comment: Can you show your url please?

Comment: @DharmbirSingh Can I send it to you in private ?

Comment: I don't have too much time to take it private. It would be great if you put here.

Comment: do you video play in browser? The Error is probably due to use of URLWithString. I think you should use -fileURLWithPath instead of URLWithString. ref : - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699247/extract-thumbnail-from-video-url

Comment: thanks @NitinGohel The video is located on a server it is not a local video hence the use of URLWithString

Comment: @sam, did you found any solution for this as i am facing same issue.

Comment: @Bucket no did not find it. Had to save thumbnails on server and get them :/ What about you ?

Comment: @Sam, Nope. still struggling

Comment: @Bucket I'm also struggling with this . Any updates ?

Comment: using @Sayooj approach works well. The issue is with copyCGImageAtTime which may be due to that specific frame not downloaded before we request thumbnail and generateCGImagesAsynchronously must be fetching frames first.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this issue by the following approach.

Swift 4.1

```
func createThumbnailForVideo(atURL videoURL: URL , completion : @escaping (UIImage?)->Void) {
    let asset = AVAsset(url: videoURL)
    let assetImgGenerate = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    let time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, preferredTimescale: 60)
    let times = [NSValue(time: time)]
    assetImgGenerate.generateCGImagesAsynchronously(forTimes: times, completionHandler: {  _, image, _, _, _ in
        if let image = image {
            let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: image)
            completion(uiImage)
        } else {
            completion(nil)
        }
    })
}
```

Hope this will help.