# The operation could not be completed when using AVAsset?

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I am trying to grab a frame from video.

But copyCGImageAtTime (in AVAssetImageGenerator) fails with this error:

> The operation could not be completed

When I specify invalid path, it throws different error, so it looks like it's not path problem.

I am trying with a MP4 file. Maybe that is a problem?

```
import Cocoa
import AVFoundation

var asset = AVAsset.init(URL: NSURL.init(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/gippeumi/test.mp4"))
var assetGen = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
assetGen.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
var tim = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0, 1)
do {
    var img = try assetGen.copyCGImageAtTime(tim, actualTime: nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
    // (Printing error here...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

" The Error is probably due to use of URLWithString. I think you should use -fileURLWithPath instead of URLWithString."

You can check this link , maybe it helps you.

[Extract thumbnail from video url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699247/extract-thumbnail-from-video-url)

Comment: It didn't worked on playground but on actual project, it works. I tried a lot of times but it never failed yet.