# Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed. Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16170 "(null)"

Tags: ios

I am using AVPlayer in my chat application but i am getting the fallowing error in selected audio files but the audio files correctly play in browser.

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could
>   not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60800024fde0 {Error
>   Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16170 "(null)"},
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-16170),
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}

I am implementing the following methods.

```
-(void)setupAVPlayerForURL:(NSURL*)url
 {
    AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
    AVPlayerItem *anItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
    playerAud = nil;
    playerAud = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:anItem];
    [self startTimer];
    [playerAud play];
    [anItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(stopAudioPlay) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil];
}

And also implement the fallowing observer.

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    //// playerAud is instance of AVPlayer 
    if (object == playerAud.currentItem && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (playerAud.currentItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusFailed) {
            NSLog(@"------player item failed:%@",playerAud.currentItem.error);
        }
    }
}

It prints the above error.
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101380/avurlasset-refuses-to-load-video

Comment: @thanks Amod Gokhale..but its not working fileURLWithPath add file keyword with the audio url.

Comment: It may have been a bug in a specific version of iOS. I remember seeing this but after updating the OS, the problem is gone.

Comment: If the file you want to play is in iCloud, you need to download it first. Similar problems occur with image files as well.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I use http url.Set `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to YES` fix the error.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) For example you can elaborate where are you using it, what effect does it have, and how it solves the question.