# Writing AVAudioPCMBuffer into an AVAudioFile compressed

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudiofile

We're working on an application which records and persists microphone input. The use of `AVAudioRecorder` was not an option, because real-time audio processing is needed.

`AVAudioEngine` is used because it provides low-level access to the input audio.

```
let audioEngine  = AVAudioEngine()
let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
let inputFormat = inputNode.inputFormat(forBus: 0)
inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: AVAudioFrameCount(inputFormat.sampleRate * sampleInterval), format: inputFormat) { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, time: AVAudioTime) -> Void in
    // sound preprocessing
    // writing to audio file
    audioFile.write(buffer.floatChannelData![0])
})
```

Our issue is that the recording is quite large. For a 5 hour recording, the output audio file is 1.2GB with `.caf` format.

```
let audioFile = AVAudioFile(forWriting: recordingPath, settings: [:], commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, interleaved: isInterleaved)
```

Is there a nice way to compress the audio file writing to it?

The default sampling frequency is 44100Hz. We will use AVAudioMixerNode to downsample the input to 20Khz (lower quality is acceptable in our case) but the size of the output won't be acceptable in size.

The recording contains large segments of background noise.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

The `.caf` container format supports AAC compression. Enable it by setting the `AVAudioFile` settings dictionary to `[AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC]`:

```
let audioFile = try! AVAudioFile(forWriting: recordingPath, settings: [AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, interleaved: isInterleaved)
```

There are other settings keys that influence the file size and quality: `AVSampleRateKey`, `AVEncoderBitRateKey` and `AVEncoderAudioQualityKey`.

p.s. you need to close your `.caf` file when you've finished with it. `AVAudioFile` doesn't have an explicit `close()` method, so you close it implicitly by nilling any references to it. Uncompressed `.caf` files seem to be playable without this, but AAC files are not.

Comment: I get error with ".wav" file format. What settings should I use instead?

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42344757/error-domain-avfoundationerrordomain-code-11800-the-operation-could-not-be-com) This is the error that I get. Even if I take filepath url.