# RPScreenRecorder.shared().startCapture won't write / keeps failing

Tags: ios, swift, avassetwriter, phasset, replaykit

When trying to record and save audio/video with ReplayKit I keep getting errors. I'm using

```
Xcode: Version 11.2.1
Swift 5
iOS 13
iPhone 7+ physical device
```

When I set the filePath I'm already using [URL(fileURLWithPath: )](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4201419/4833705). The file extension and `AVFileType` are both `.mp4`. I check to see if the file already exists in the `FileManager` and if so I remove it: `do { try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: videoURL) }`. I tried to change the path itself to "Library/Caches/" like in [@florianSAP answer](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121902) which didn't work.

Here the 3 errors:

```
// 1. from recording
if !self.assetWriter.startWriting() {
    print("Can't write")
    return
}

// 2. from recording
if self.assetWriter.status == AVAssetWriter.Status.failed {
    print("StartCapture Error Occurred, Status = \(self.assetWriter.status.rawValue), \(self.assetWriter.error?.localizedDescription) \(self.assetWriter.error?.debugDescription)")
    return
}

// 3. this one is when trying to save the url in the PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo completionHandler
if let error = error {
    print("PHAssetChangeRequest Video Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    return
}

// 4. this isn't an error but inside the switch rpSampleBufferType { } statement "not a video sample" kept printing out
```

The error messages are:

> StartCapture Error Occurred, Status = 3, The operation could not be
>   completed Optional(Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800
>   "The operation could not be completed"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-17508),
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x2833a93b0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain
>   Code=-17508 "(null)"}})
>
> PHAssetChangeRequest Video Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (PHPhotosErrorDomain
>   error -1.)

**Where am I going to wrong at?**

Start Recording

```
let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.shared()
var assetWriter: AVAssetWriter!
var videoURL: URL!
var videoInput: AVAssetWriterInput!
var audioMicInput: AVAssetWriterInput!

guard let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first else { return }

videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath.appending(UUID().uuidString + ".mp4"))

guard let videoURL = videoURL else { return }

do {
    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: videoURL)
} catch {}

do {
    try assetWriter = AVAssetWriter(outputURL: videoURL, fileType: .mp4) // AVAssetWriter(url: videoURL, fileType: .mp4) didn't make a difference
} catch {}

let videoSettings: [String : Any] = [
    AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.h264,
    AVVideoWidthKey: view.bounds.width,
    AVVideoHeightKey: view.bounds.height
]

videoInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .video, outputSettings: videoSettings)
videoInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
if assetWriter.canAdd(videoInput) {
    assetWriter.add(videoInput)
}

let audioSettings: [String:Any] = [AVFormatIDKey : kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 2,
    AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0,
    AVEncoderBitRateKey: 192000
]

audioMicInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .audio, outputSettings: audioSettings)
audioMicInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
if assetWriter.canAdd(audioMicInput) {
    assetWriter.add(audioMicInput)
}

guard recorder.isAvailable else { return }

recorder.startCapture(handler: { (cmSampleBuffer, rpSampleBufferType, err) in

    if let err = err { return }

    // I tried to check if this was ready and added the below code to it but it made no difference
    // if CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(cmSampleBuffer) { ... the code below was put in here ... }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        switch rpSampleBufferType {
           case .video:

                if self.assetWriter.status == AVAssetWriter.Status.unknown {

                    if !self.assetWriter.startWriting() {
                        print("Can't write")
                        return
                    }

                    print("Starting writing")
                    self.assetWriter.startWriting()
                    self.assetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime:  CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(cmSampleBuffer))
                }

                if self.assetWriter.status == AVAssetWriter.Status.failed {
                    print("StartCapture Error Occurred, Status = \(self.assetWriter.status.rawValue), \(self.assetWriter.error?.localizedDescription) \(self.assetWriter.error?.debugDescription)")
                    return
                }

                if self.assetWriter.status == AVAssetWriter.Status.writing {
                    if self.videoInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
                        if self.videoInput.append(cmSampleBuffer) == false {
                            print("problem writing video")
                        }
                    }
                }

            case .audioMic:
                if self.audioMicInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
                    print("audioMic data added")
                    self.audioMicInput.append(cmSampleBuffer)
                }

            default:
                print("not a video sample")
            }
        }
    }

}, completionHandler: { (error) in

    if let error = error { return }
})
```

Stop Recording:

```
recorder.stopCapture { (error) in

    if let error = error { return }

    guard let videoInput = self.videoInput else { return }
    guard let audioMicInput = self.audioMicInput else { return }
    guard let assetWriter = self.assetWriter else { return }
    guard let videoURL = videoURL else { return }

    videoInput.markAsFinished()
    audioMicInput.markAsFinished()
    assetWriter.finishWriting(completionHandler: {

        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: videoUrl)
            }) { (saved, error) in

                if let error = error {
                    print("PHAssetChangeRequest Video Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }

                if saved {
                    // ... show success message
                }
            }
    })
}
```

RPScreenRecorder Delegate that never gets called:

```
func screenRecorder(_ screenRecorder: RPScreenRecorder, didStopRecordingWith previewViewController: RPPreviewViewController?, error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by doing 2 things:

1- The first thing I did was I change the `videoURL`’s filePath from:

```
// Old Way that was causing some sort of path error
videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath.appending(UUID().uuidString + ".mp4"))

// This is what the Old Path looked like. Look at the series of numbers beginning with 506... directly after Documents
///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AAEF38A2-7AF1-4A32-A612-296B1584A764/Documents506D36BA-0C27-466A-A0BA-C197481F471A.mp4
```

to

```
// New Way that got the path to work
let dirPath = "\(documentsPath)/Videos_\(UUID().uuidString).mp4"
videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath)

// This is what the new path looks like. After Documents there is now a forward slash, the word Videos with an underscore, and then the series of numbers beginning with 506...
///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AAEF38A2-7AF1-4A32-A612-296B1584A764/Documents/Videos_506D36BA-0C27-466A-A0BA-C197481F471A.mp4
```

2 -The second thing I did was change the code inside the `recorder.startCapture(handler: { (cmSampleBuffer, rpSampleBufferType, err)`:

```
recorder.startCapture(handler: { (cmSampleBuffer, rpSampleBufferType, err) in

    if let err = err { return }

    if CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(cmSampleBuffer) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            switch rpSampleBufferType {
            case .video:

                print("writing sample....")

                if self.assetWriter?.status == AVAssetWriter.Status.unknown {

                    print("Started writing")
                    self.assetWriter?.startWriting()
                    self.assetWriter?.startSession(atSourceTime: CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(cmSampleBuffer))
                }

                if self.assetWriter.status == AVAssetWriter.Status.failed {
                    print("StartCapture Error Occurred, Status = \(self.assetWriter.status.rawValue), \(self.assetWriter.error!.localizedDescription) \(self.assetWriter.error.debugDescription)")
                     return
                }

                if self.assetWriter.status == AVAssetWriter.Status.writing {
                    if self.videoInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
                        print("Writing a sample")
                        if self.videoInput.append(cmSampleBuffer) == false {
                             print("problem writing video")
                        }
                     }
                 }

            case .audioMic:
                if self.audioMicInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
                    print("audioMic data added")
                    self.audioMicInput.append(cmSampleBuffer)
                }

            default:
                print("not a video sample")
            }
        }
}, completionHandler: { (error) in

    if let error = error { return }
})
```

This has nothing to do with the actual problem I ran into but if audio isn't syncing then you have to add this code below to `viewDidLoad`. I got it from the [comments section here](https://iphoneappcode.blogspot.com/2019/05/how-to-recordcapture-screen-in-ios-with.html).

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .videoRecording, options: [.defaultToSpeaker])
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
} catch {
    #if DEBUG
    print("Setting category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback failed.")
    #endif
}
```

If you need to find the meaning of error codes you can look here https://www.osstatus.com. It helped me find `11800` for this problem but not `17508`.

Comment: nah, I didn’t download it yet. Why would it not work in iOS 14?

Comment: Yes getting issues my brother

Comment: On which line and what are the issues